# Delete all custom posts then upload a new CSV of events

Tags: custom-post-types, admin, security, csv

I was having an issues with deleting all posts and then re-uploading a new CSV of events to a custom post type 'events' and managed to put together a solution together that works.Hopefully this will help other with the same issue.

Now my question is, is this a secure way of handling this problem and if it's not, what do i need to do?

Functions.php

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------
Delete post and insert new posts from CSV file
------------------------------------------------------------*/


function jab_admin_notice() {
    // Add buttons to post type
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if( 'events' == $screen->post_type && 'edit' == $screen->base ){
        echo "<div class='updated'></p>";
        echo "<a class='button button-primary' href='".strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'&')."&insert_event_posts'>Insert Posts</a>";
        echo "<a class='button button-primary' href='".strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'&')."&delete_event_posts'>delete Posts</a></p></div>";
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'jab_admin_notice' );


add_action( "admin_init", function() {

    global $wpdb;

        //UPLOADS CSV - ADDS POSTS
        //check for parameter.
        if ( isset( $_GET["insert_event_posts"] ) ) {
            //get csv path      
            $path = "/calendar.csv";

            //Open the CSV file
            $file = fopen(__DIR__ . $path, 'r');
            while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {

                //$line is an array of the csv elements                 
                $post["id"] = wp_insert_post( array(
                    "post_title" => $line[0],
                    "post_author" => 1,
                    "post_content" => $line[5],
                    "post_type" => 'events',
                    "post_status" => "publish"
                ));
            //Update any linked meta data
            update_post_meta( $post["id"], 'meta-box-startdate', $line[1] .'-'.  $line[2]);
            update_post_meta( $post["id"], 'meta-box-enddate', $line[3] .'-'. $line[4] );
            }
            fclose($file);

      //check for parameter.
      } else if( isset( $_GET["delete_event_posts"] ) ) {

        //REMOVES ALL POST
        $args = array (
            'post_type' => 'events',
            'nopaging' => true
        );
        $query = new WP_Query ($args);
        while ($query->have_posts ()) {
            $query->the_post ();
            $id = get_the_ID ();
            wp_delete_post ($id, false);
        }
        wp_reset_postdata ();   

    } else {  
        //DO NOTHING
        return;
    }      

});
```

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks

Comment: What was the problem ?

Comment: Is this the most secure method for updating using a CSV in the admin area? 

Also how can i make it so that just an admin is able to see the buttons?

Comment: I asked for the issue you had before to make this code.

Comment: I'm asking if this is the best secure way of deleting and uploading a CSV to a custom post type in the admin area. Before i was using mySQL to do this but didn't now how to link that to the admin area.